# Find the $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ that minimizes $\int_0^1 \left| e^t - (a - bt + ct^2) \right| dt$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Find the $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ that minimizes
>   $$\int_0^1 \left| e^t - (a + bt + ct^2) \right|^2 dt \tag{A}$$

My context is that I've just learned about how a convex subset of an inner product space is guaranteed to have unique minimizing vector for any vector in that inner product space. Here I think that both $e^t$ and every $(a + bt + ct^2)$ are vectors in the inner product space $L^2[0,1]$, so (A) is of the form

$$\|x - y\|^2 = \langle x-y, x-y \rangle \tag{B}$$

Let's label the unique minimization vector of (A) and (B) as $a_0 + b_0t + c_0t = y_0$. And label $M$ the subspace of all quadratic functions on $[0,1]$.

I've also learned that for any element $y \in M$, $y \neq y_o$ that we have

$$\langle x - y_0, y \rangle = 0 \tag{C}$$

So I've been intending to solve the problem by finding an $a_0, b_0, c_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\int_0^1 \left| \left( e^t - (a_0 + b_0t + c_0t^2) \right) \left(a + bt + ct^2\right) \right|^2 dt = 0$$

Is this the right direction, because it seems like there would be a mountain of arithmetic ahead? I did try a shortcut: since the argument of the integral in (C) is continuous and greater than zero, it must be equal to zero. But that resulted in $e^t = a_0 + b_0t + c_0t^2$, which isn't possible.

Any hints would be great, thank you.

Comment: Look at the orthogonal projection onto the subspace of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you studied orthonormal sets, Gram Schmidt process and projections? If $\{e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n\}$ is an orthonormal set in an inner product space and $v$ is a given vector then $\|v-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_ie_i\|$ is minized when $a_i= \langle v, e_i \rangle$. So what you have to do is to use Gram Schmidt process to find an orthonormal basis for the space spanned by $1,t,t^{2}$ and then use above formula.

Answer (score 1):

By evaluating the integral explicitly one can find
$$f(a,b,c)=\int_0^1(e^t+a+bt+ct^2)dt$$
Then by setting each of $\large{\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}}$, $\large{\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}}$, $\large{\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}}$ equal to $0$ one create a set of simultaneous equations that result in
$$a=105-39e$$
$$b=-588+216e$$
$$c=570-210e$$
In this case the value of the integral is
$$f(105-39e,-588+216e,570-210e)= -\frac{3667}2 +1350 e - \frac{497}2 e^2≈0.0000278354444862696$$